# Поиск максимального значения в просуммированной таблице SQL

Tags: sql, суммирование

Есть таблица с полями ID и Number. ID могут повторяться, Number - произвольные численные значения. Надо найти ID с максимальной суммой. Просуммировать я их смог, а вот как делать дальше, ума не приложу

SELECT ID, sum(Number) FROM tab1 GROUP BY ID;

Догадываюсь, что нужна совсем какая-то мелочь, но моих знаний еще не хватает даже на правильный поиск. Буду очень рад помощи.

Comment: Отсортируйте по сумме в порядке убывания, и возьмите первую строку.

Comment: @Sergey Moiseenko, интересное решение. Похоже на костыль, конечно, но оно работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Это не костыль а вполне штатное решение. Ограничение: если имеется несколько ID с одинаковой, и при этом максимальной, суммой - будет выведен только один, причём непредсказуемо какой именно.

Answer (score 0):

Drawen.

Можно еще и вот так сделать:

```
declare @t table (id int not null, num bigint);

insert into @t
values
(1, 10),
(2, 11),
(3, 20),
(4, 7),
(5, 18),
(2, 6),
(6, 3),
(1, 6),
(3, 9),
(4, 15),
(5, 10),
(3, 22);

--оконная функция row_number()
select id, sumnum from 
(
    select id, sum(num) as sumnum, 
        row_number() over(order by sum(num) desc) as rownum 
    from @t
    group by id
) t1
where rownum = 1
```